# Delphi 5 TntUnicodeVcl_R50.bpl can`t be installed it is not a design time package

Tags: delphi, unicode, delphi-5

I am trying to install an component TntUnicodeVcl_R50 (it is .dpk - delphi package) to Delphi but every time I try to install it an error pops up that it can`t be installed because it is not a run time package. Do anybody have any suggestion how to avoid this error and install the package? I need it to be done under Delphi 5.

Thank you very much for your answer.

[image: Error]

Comment: The R in the name was supposed to be your clue. The R means do not try to install me.  D means "install me".  Sometimes package maintainers use this convention (D50). Others put Dsgn in the package name if it is meant to be installed.

Answer (score 3):

If you read the error message in your image you will see that it actually states that the package cannot be installed because it is not a **design time** package.

Which makes sense. The package you are trying to install is `TntUnicodeVcl_R50` where there `R` indicates run time. You need to install the design time package. One would guess that it is named `TntUnicodeVcl_D50`.

Answer (score 0):

You need to install another package. This one should be only compiled. Please take a look for design-time packages (i.e. TntUnicodeVcl_D50) to install